# Django admin display groups horizontally

Tags: django, datetime, django-admin, alignment

How do I get Django admin to display groups horizontally?  If I have 3 adjacent datetime fields, I'd rather them take up 1 row, not 3.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have you tried grouping your fieldsets into tuples?:

```
fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('name','description',('start_date','end_date'), 'location', ('latitude','longitude'))
        }),
    )
```

Comment: Tested Django==1.8.4. Worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

The way I've done it is to make a custom admin template. You can just take the one that comes with django, copy it, and edit the parts you want changed.

A good tutorial on how to do that is on the django site. Specifically, there is a part on  [making a custom admin template](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/#customize-the-admin-look-and-feel).

Comment: This technique can be useful for advanced stuff, but there is no reason to do it just to put several fields on the same line.  Just group your fieldsets into tuples, as shown in andybak's answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is been tested on Django==2.0.7 and worked like a charm, a really important piece of advice regarding the use of the param "fieldsets" is that u cant use "fields" property at same time , otherwise u will get the following error on ur console :

```
(admin.E005) Both 'fieldsets' and 'fields' are specified.
```

The syntax would be smth like these :

```
fieldsets = (
    ('General Information', {
        'fields': (
            ("id", "created_at", "updated_at",),
            ("name", "coupon_type", "discount", "is_active",),
            ("quantity", "minumum_quantity", "before_expire",),
        ),
    }),
    ('Expiration Dates', {
        'fields': (
            ("expiration_from", "expiration_to",),
        ),
    }),
    ('Grants for', {
        'fields': (
            "products", "campaigns_product", "sellers", "platforms",
        ),
    }),
)
```